# Error while compiling Cuda Accelerated Linpack hpl_2.0_FERMI

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04, compile, cuda

I use

- Ubuntu 11.04 x86_64
- CUDA 4.0
- OpenMpi 1.4stable
- MKL

When I compile, I get this error:

```
ar r -L/home/limksadmin/hpl-2.0_FERMI_v13/lib/CUDA/libhpl.a  HPL_dlacpy.o           HPL_dlatcpy.o          HPL_fprintf.o HPL_warn.o             HPL_abort.o            HPL_dlaprnt.o HPL_dlange.o HPL_dlamch.o
ar: -L/home/limksadmin/hpl-2.0_FERMI_v13/lib/CUDA/libhpl.a: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [lib.grd] Error 9
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/limksadmin/hpl-2.0_FERMI_v13/src/auxil/CUDA'
make[1]: *** [build_src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/limksadmin/hpl-2.0_FERMI_v13'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Make.CUDA:

```
LAdir        = /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64
LAlib        = -L $(TOPdir)/src/cuda  -ldgemm -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -L$(LAdir) -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5
MPdir        = /usr/local/mpi/openmpi
MPinc        = -I$(MPdir)/include
MPlib        = -L$(MPdir)/lib/libmpi.so

CC      = /usr/local/mpi/openmpi/bin/mpicc
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
ar: -L/home/limksadmin/hpl-2.0_FERMI_v13/lib/CUDA/libhpl.a: No such file or directory
```

This line is stating that it can't find the proper HPL static library file for CUDA. One thing you could try to do (if you know that you are 100% positive everything is set correctly in your Makefile) is to add that exact path, without the file name, to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/limksadmin/hpl-2.0_FERMI_v13/lib/CUDA/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `-openmp` with `-fopenmp` in `CCFLAGS` variable.

It's specified like this for use with Intel compiler, but such notion confuses gcc (which is base of default ubuntu OpenMPI installation), making it think that `penmp` is desired output filename (which is not actually true).